# Calisthenics objects, and primitive wrapped in Objects

Tags: java

I m working on calisthenics objects and I'm actually having some troubles while trying to follow the calisthenic objects rules.

In fact, I m stuck with the one telling that we have to wrap all the primitives inside of objects.

**Context**

I'm having a Euro object that looks like :

```
public class Euro {

    private double amount;

    public Euro(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Euro other = (Euro)obj;
        return other.amount == amount;
    }

    // Problems come here
    public Euro multiply(double priceValue) {
        Euro newAmount = new Euro(amount * priceValue);
        return newAmount;
    }

    public Euro add(Euro valueToAdd) {
        Euro newPrice = new Euro(amount + valueToAdd.amount);
        return newPrice;
    }
}
```

And I m having a Discount class. In fact, we can apply Discount on product, the the amount we obtain is a Euro :

```
public class Discount {

    private double value;

    public Discount(double theValue) {
        value = theValue;
    }

    public Euro apply(Euro price) {
        return price.multiply(value);
    }
}
```

**Problem**

My problems appear on the multiply method of the Euro object.

In fact, currently, I m accepting a double as parameter, and it doesn't follow the rule of wrapping all primitives in objects... Moreover, a "double" in a business context doesn't mean anything at all. I m a little bit stuck with this example and don't know how to bypass this.

Moreover, I don't want to use getter / setter on this implementation...

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Sylvain Boisse already summed up the most important points I was about to say, so the addition comes as a small comment: I noticed, that you use double to represent a monetary value. This is generally a bad idea, as floating point types do not have an exact representation of numbers in all cases. For money, use some kind of integer/long type (in cents obviously) or BigDecimal.

Comment: @mtj Good comment. This also allows good handling on [rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cash_rounding#Rounding_with_0.05_or_5_intervals): there are *legal* requirements on rounding the cents (if the seller applies a 30% rabate on 7.99€ etc.), which a dedicated class would allow.

Answer (score 3):

That cannot work with this Object hierarchy. You have a contradiction in your katas, that requires some messy stuff.

Here's an extract of the katas of your previous similar Question (emphasis mine):

> One level of indentation per method
>   Don’t use the ELSE keyword
>   **Wrap all primitives** and Strings
>   First class collections
>   One dot per line
>   Don’t abbreviate
>   Keep all entities small (50 lines)
>   No classes with more than two instance variables
>   **No getters**/setters/properties

You're dealing with two double values of distinct meaning (a discount rate and a cost). Because of kata `Wrap all primitives`, you wrap them both in two, *distinct* object.

Now you need these primitives (the `double`s) to interact (multiply). No Object  can access both values, since the kata `No getters` prevents one from accessing the other's internal values!

---

### A Solution

You've successfully made two primitives interact elsewhere. It was in the `Euro` class:

```
public Euro add(Euro valueToAdd) {
    Euro newPrice = new Euro(amount + valueToAdd.amount);
    return newPrice;
}
```

A primitive wrapper is able to make interactions with a primitive wrapper of the same type, or with a subclass of it. Then that is what you should do: all `double` wrappers that will want to interact *must* extend a common `double` wrapper. (Note 1: I didn't spot any rule against subclassing, yet you did not subclass anything. Note 2: does subclassing bypass kata `No classes with more than two instance variables`? Don't need it, just curious).

So here's the code:

MonetaryQuantity.java (**Edit: Changed the name, fits better**) is a parent class to all stuff that will ever interact with money etc.)

```
public class MonetaryQuantity {
    protected double value; // Can be accessed by any Money-related class
    public MonetaryQuantity(double theValue) {
        value = theValue;
    }
}
```

Euro.java:

```
public class Euro extends MonetaryQuantity{
    public Euro(double amount) {
        super(amount);
    }
    public Euro apply(Discount discount) {
        Euro newAmount = discount.applyOn(this);
        return newAmount;
    }
    public Euro add(Euro valueToAdd) {
        Euro newPrice = new Euro(value + valueToAdd.value);
        return newPrice;
    }
}
```

Discount.java:

```
public class Discount extends MonetaryQuantity{
    public Discount(double theValue) {
        super(theValue);
    }
    public Euro applyOn(Euro price) {
        // Discount can access Euro.value because both handle money (similar business sphere)
        return new Euro(price.value * value); 
    }
}
```

---

### Notes on style

Why do you apply a Euro on a Discount? Usually, we apply a Discount on a Price. I prefer `price.apply(discount)`. I kept discount.applyOn(price).

Naming `value` on `Euro` is a bit clumsy. It may be a cost, or a price, those things are different. Maybe two subclasses?

Naming `value` on `Discount` is just bad. It should be a `rate`. The Object might even be called a `DiscountRate`, because you could have an `AbsoluteDiscount` (-10€). `Discount` would be an `interface` with a `Euro applyOn(Euro price)` method. Note I moved the implementation of the discount from the `Euro` class to the `Discount` class for just that reason. `Euro` just forwards it to `Discount`.

**Note:** with these Katas, I cannot extract an `add` and a `multiply` method into the wrapper class (although I would really like it!) because it would have to return the proper Wrapper sub-class (not the primitive result). It would only work with C-style result-passing in parameters AND require a `setValue()`:

```
public class MonetaryQuantity {
    public <T extends MonetaryQuantity> T add(MonetaryQuantity valueToAdd, T returnValue) {
        double newValue = value + valueToAdd.value;
        returnValue.set(newValue); // This is against a kata!
        return newValue;
    }
}
```

This is all quite frustrating.

---

### The `equals()` method

It's broken everywhere. It fails with `ClassCastExceptions`, `NullPointerExceptions` etc. Make `instanceof` checks and handle the mismatch cases properly.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, I m going to study your thoughts and try to apply them in my context. This kata is just killing me x)

Comment: One or two remarks, DoubleWrapper doesn't make a perfect sense in a business context. Moreover using a Money parent class to deal with Euro and a Discount seems to be weird, since Discount is not a cost, but a rate

Comment: I know, I couldn't find anything at the time. Now I think of it, it could be a `MonetaryQuantity` ? This encompasses a cost, a price, or a discount. I may edit my answer if you like it.

Comment: How can the private `value` member of `MonetaryQuantity` be accessed in subclasses?

Comment: Renaming `DoubleWrapper` to `MonetaryQuantity` doesn't change the fact that it is a wrapper around `double`, and its subclasses have nothing in common other than the fact that they share a floating-point representation. It seems like a cumbersome workaround to satisfy a pointless rule banning primitives.

Comment: Good catch! I suppose making it protected wouldn't go against the katas. I don't intend it to remove representation as a floating point as @mtj pointed at, that's beyond the scope of my answer and may warrant a whole other answer. And yes it's cumbersome to use these wrappers, that frustration is part of the point of those rules, I believe... Successfullly following those is strangely satisfying though. You really have to dig in OOP concepts and keep a global vue. Do you see a *less* cumbersome way?